# How to make inventory pause screens in Gamemaker?

Tags: game-maker

I'm making a game in Game Maker, and I want to know how to make it so you can pause into an inventory screen and then go back to the same position you were in (also the same room) after you press a back button. It would also be great if all the dead enemies were dead and the alive ones were at the same position also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go into an inventory screen, you can create a new room which you can customize to your liking.

To have all of the instances of your room "freeze", use the **instance_deactivate_all()** method.

To "unfreeze" all of the instances in your room,  use the **instance_activate_all()** method.

If we break up your code and look at the individual parts, it should resemble the below:

1. In Key Press event, go to your inventory room.
2. In Room Exit event of original room, freeze all instances.
3. Code your Inventory room as you see fit.
4. In Key Press event, go back to original room.
5. In Room Enter event of original room, unfreeze all instances.

Comment: Thanks! I hope people come and upvote this, you deserve it.